# Mounting as a storage in Android file system from my app (FUSE?)

Tags: android, file, stream, storage, fuse

Is there an option to mount as a file system on **non-rooted** Android device, as it is possible on Windows and Linux via drivers (fuse for Linux)?

I want to make a filesystem, like the SD Card Storage, but in the user space (so that my app can serve read/write/create/delete requests to the other apps), visible from 3-rd party apps, like File Browsers. I want to stream these files directly from my virtual file system to 3-rd party apps (the other apps should be able to open the file, read and write in specific position of the file).

For example, I want to put one video file in the root directory of my new file system and open the file with any 3rd party Video Player from any 3rd party File Browser, without copying the file in the Internal Android Storage.

I read about FUSE - [Link](https://source.android.com/docs/core/storage/fuse-passthrough), but I can`t understand is this some Android internals which are not open for Android developers or they are open for the developers to use somehow and create their own virtual file system? Can we make any changes from our Android App to the Android File System?

I searched a lot but I couldn't find information is it possible or not. Can someone give me an evidence (any document maybe) whether is this possible or not, and if there is an opportunity - how?

**Edit**:

If I use **DocumentProvider** or **FileProvider**, my app is able to serve only ParcelableFileDescryptor for the other 3rd party apps.

**I want to handle 3rd party app's open(..) / read(bytes[], ..) / write(bytes[], ..) requests, to put these bytes[] directly to my cloud.**

**For example: write(bytes[], offset, count) request for position N to position N+500), because my interface allows that (only the bytes[] from position N to position N+500 from the file in the cloud will be changed, not the whole file).**

Another example is that: When I play video with 3rd party video player from my cloud storage, the video player doesn`t need the whole file, it will need only separate bytes from the file, related to the position in the video, gotten from the app with read(bytes[], offset, count) requests by chunks. So I want to serve these bytes directly to the external player as a stream from my cloud, without copying the whole file before that, because this will take a lot of time.

If I use DocumentProvider or FileProvider, when another app wants my video file, firstly I need to download the whole file, then I have to serve the ParcelableFileDescryptor to the 3rd party app.. And then the AndroidOS will kill my DocumentProvider process. That is why I want to mount as a file system, like the SDCard of the Android Device, and handle the read/write requests from the apps.
Is that possible and am I missing something about the DocumentProvider?

Comment: Extend DocumentProvider.

Comment: You can also add an intent filter for ACTION_GET_CONTENT in manifest file.

Comment: I edited the first comment, please read it. I don`t think, that DocumentProvider or FileProvider will resolve my problem.

Comment: I did not say to use FileProvider. And indeed random access is not supported in DocumentProvider i think or with uries obtained by ACTION_GET_CONTENT. Sorry that i did not realise you needed random access before.